# HMS Ads Kit-Error code 4 is returned when obtaining ads

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-ads

When I use **HUAWEI Ads SDK** in **Android Studio** to load native ads and display them on my app，

> Error code -4

is returned，and log information:

> The ad is being requested and cannot be requested again.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possible cause is that the loadAd() method is repeatedly executed in your code. Check whether loadAd() is repeatedly called in your code or whether the retry interval is too short in Logcat.